# Significato e uso del verbo "sbalzare" in senso figurato

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, verbs

Sul [sito web della Rai](http://www.wr6.rai.it/dl/portaleRadio/media/ContentItem-52cd30b5-91d0-441b-8579-90e93f16fd9a.html) si trovano i podcast del programma di radio "Ad alta voce. Leggere il Decamerone" di Alberto Asor Rosa e Adolfo Moriconi. All'inizio della seconda parte della puntata 43, Moriconi pronuncia queste parole (grassetto mio):

> Il narratore di turno è Panfilo, un narratore pieno di parole, un narratore molto verboso, quindi anche un narratore, secondo il criterio della quantità delle parole che serve appunto ad identificare la personalità del narratore come personaggio... ci porta a dire che Boccaccio in questo caso aveva proprio voglia di **sbalzarlo** bene, bene a fondo, questo personaggio di Panfilo. Infatti [...]

Il verbo che ho evidenziato sopra, "sbalzare", ha attirato la mia attenzione perché era sconosciuto per me. Ricercandolo sul [vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sbalzare), immagino che abbia un senso figurato più o meno simile a quello che si fa in questi esempi

> *la temperatura è sbalzata a dieci gradi sotto zero; non si capisce come sia sbalzato da semplice impiegato a capufficio*;

Non ne sono per niente sicura, però, perché nelle frasi precedenti il verbo è intransitivo, mentre Moriconi ne fa un uso transitivo (ma gli usi transitivi riportati nel dizionario non sembrano avere senso in questo contesto). Qualcuno di voi saprebbe dare un po' di luce su questo punto?

Poi, il Treccani spiega l'accezione a cui corrispondono gli esempi citati nel modo che segue:

> Fare un balzo improvviso, spec. in senso fig. (ma più com. *balzare*)

Dovrei capire che Moriconi fa un uso del verbo poco comune? Anche negli esempi del Treccani si usa più spesso "balzare"? Cioè, si potrebbe dire "la temperatura è balzata a dieci gradi sotto zero" e "non si capisce come sia balzato da semplice impiegato a capufficio"? Potrei anche costruire una frase con significato simile a quella di Moriconi usando "balzare"?

Comment: L'intervento di Alberto Asor Rosa è al minuto 11:53 della stessa puntata. P.S.: chiedo scusa per il paternalismo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direi che il riferimento è allo [sbalzo](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sbalzo_(arte)) (repujado in spagnolo), da cui il verbo "sbalzare" con il significato che trovi al punto 3 di [questa definizione](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sbalzare/).

Quindi, Moriconi paragona il processo creativo del personaggio all'esecuzione di uno sbalzo da parte di un artigiano, quindi dicendo che Boccaccio vuole "sbalzare bene" e a fondo il personaggio vuole intendere che (metaforicamente) Boccaccio crea uno sbalzo molto ben definito e preciso, quindi un personaggio altrettanto ben definito e preciso. Una metafora sicuramente adatta al contesto, anche se probabilmente non usatissima (ma direi che qualunque italiano di media cultura e istruzione la capirebbe).

Comment: Quindi, si tratterebbe di un uso figurato insolito di questa tecnica di lavorazione del metallo? Potresti aggiungere qualche dettaglio alla tua risposta, per favore? Così com'è, non riesco a capirla bene. Cosa vuol dire Moriconi con questa espressione? Che Boccaccio voleva lavorare sul personaggio di Panfilo come si faceva con le lastre di metallo? E Moriconi inventa lì per lì questa idea di paragonare il lavoro di un scrittore a quello di un artigiano del metallo?

Comment: @Charo, non ti sottovalutare, hai capito perfettamente. Comunque, le figure di linguaggio non sono affatto insolite, e i tipi come Moriconi non le inventano lì per lì. Poteva dire disegnarlo, scolpirlo, delinearlo, ma ha scelto sbalzarlo. Bella scelta. Non vedi Panfilo messo ben bene in "rilievo" dal Boccaccio?

Comment: @GiuseppeRomanazzi: Quindi il significato sarebbe "mettere in rilievo" perché si tratta appunto di una tecnica per dare rilievo alle lastre di metallo? Cioè, Boccaccio voleva che il personaggio di Dioneo avesse un ruolo rilevante nella cornice del Decameron? Oppure il senso sarebbe che voleva che si trattasse di un personaggio molto ben definito?

Comment: @GiuseppeRomanazzi: Non essere paternalista. Se hai delle opinioni da esprimere sulla lingua italiana e sul suo lessico, sei il benvenuto, ma “non ti sottovalutare”, “hai capito perfettamente” e simili sono fuori luogo.

Comment: @Charo Questo lo spiegano loro molto meglio di me. Per esempio, Alberto Asor Rosa in un intervento dice: "Non v'è alcun dubbio che Boccaccio gli abbia riservato un ruolo di notevole rilievo nella struttura narrativa della cornice". Il personaggio narratore di cui parlano è Panfilo.

Comment: @Charo esatto, l'autore paragona il processo creativo del personaggio all'esecuzione di uno sbalzo da parte di un artigiano, quindi dicendo che Boccaccio vuole "sbalzare bene" e a fondo il personaggio vuole intendere che (metaforicamente) Boccaccio crea uno sbalzo molto ben definito e preciso, quindi un personaggio altrettanto ben definito e preciso.

Comment: Grazie, @persson: potresti aggiungerlo alla risposta? E, per quanto ho capito dai commenti, non si tratta di un uso tanto insolito di "sbalzare" in senso figurato, vero?

Comment: Ah, ecco! Ricercando "sbalzare il personaggio" e "sbalzare un personaggio" su Google ho trovato qualche altra occorrenza di questo uso figurato.